# Derivative of a conditional density

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives

I would like to find the derivative of $f(y|u)$ with respect to c where $f(y|u)$ follows $N(x,a^2)$ and $x=g(c)$. So far I got
$f'(y|u)$ = $-0.5a^2N(x,a^2)d/dc(y|u-x)$. But how do I take the derivative of $y|u$ if I don't know that. Only I know is that $y|u$ follows normal and $y=x+e$ where $e$ is random noise.

Answer (score 1):

The density of $N(g(c), a^2)$ evaluated at some number $y$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a^2}} e^{-(y-g(c))^2/(2a^2)}$. Treat $y$ and $a$ as fixed, and take the derivative of this expression with respect to $c$. The result should involve both $g(c)$ and $g'(c)$.